# Radeon HD 5450 vs Radeon HD 5970

Tags: graphics-card, upgrade, gpu, amd-radeon

Can I upgrade from one to the next? I have a Dell Studio XPS and I am unsure about power/size constraints.

Comment: I spoke with Dell support and a Dell Studio XPS 7100 can support: ATI 5850 and 5870 as the high end GPUs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HD 5450 is an *entry-level* card intended for HTPC applications and draws very little power, at 19.1 watts ([source](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5450-overview/pages/hd-5450-overview.aspx#2)).  The HD 5970 is a *top-of-the-line dual-GPU* video card and requires as much as 294 watts to operate ([source](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5970/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5970-overview.aspx#2)).  You will need a PSU with one 8-pin and one 6-pin PCI Express power connector, and it needs to be able to supply at least 650 watts ([source](http://www.amd.com/us/products/desktop/graphics/ati-radeon-hd-5000/hd-5970/Pages/ati-radeon-hd-5970-overview.aspx#3)).  As systems of the type you mentioned generally do not have an adequate power supply (OEM power supplies are often inadequate for major upgrades, except for expensive high-end gaming systems), you will probably need to upgrade the power supply.  You may want to consider any one of the modular Corsair PSUs listed [here](http://www.corsair.com/power-supplies/modular-psus/professional-series-1.html) on the Corsair website.

You can probably make the upgrade, but you will need to replace the stock power supply.